# Why would an html text input name cause a submit input not to set?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an `html` form, with 13 `<input>` fields and approx. 92 different rows, created using `php` which pulls the records from a `mySQL` database. For some reason when I have a name assigned to this one field, it causes my `<input type="submit" name="update_submit">` button not to set. If I change the name, it doesn't matter, but if I remove the name it will allow the other fields to update just fine.

Here is a snippet of my form code( `$i` is auto incremented):

Up Top...

```
<form method="post" action="process_form.php">
<table>
<tr>
```

Further down...

```
echo "<td align=\"center\" class=\"edit_emp_comp_exp_cell\"><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"10\" size=\"10\" id=\"Lic_Comp_Exp$i\" name=\"Lic_Comp_Exp[]\" value=\"" . $emp_query['Lic_Comp_Exp'] . "\">";

<input type="submit" name="update_submit" style="width:100px;" value="UPDATE">
```

Further down...

```
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my process_form:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_submit']))
{
$id = $_POST['Emp_ID'];
$name = $_POST['Emp_Name'];
$phone = $_POST['Emp_Phone'];
$start = $_POST['Start_Date'];
$leave = $_POST['Paid_Leave'];
$aca = $_POST['Emp_ACA'];
$licauth = $_POST['Lic_Auth_ID'];
$authexp = $_POST['Lic_Auth_Exp'];
$liccomp = $_POST['Lic_Comp_ID'];
$compexp = $_POST['Lic_Comp_Exp'];
$miscp  = $_POST['MiscP_ID'];
$position = $_POST['Pos_ID'];
$active = $_POST['activeBox'];
$i = 0;

foreach($id as $update) 
        {
        if (!isset($active[$i])) { $active[$i] = 0; }
        $sql = ("UPDATE employee SET Emp_Name = '$name[$i]', Emp_Phone = '$phone[$i]', Emp_Start_Date = '$start[$i]', Paid_Leave = '$leave[$i]', Emp_ACA = '$aca[$i]', Lic_Auth_ID = '$licauth[$i]', Lic_Auth_Exp = '$authexp[$i]', Lic_Comp_ID = '$liccomp[$i]', Lic_Comp_Exp = '$compexp[$i]', MiscP_ID = '$miscp[$i]', Pos_ID = '$position[$i]', Emp_Active = '$active[$i]' WHERE Emp_ID = '$update'");

        echo "SQL: " . $sql . "<br>";

        if(!$result_employee_update = $mysqli->query($sql))
            {
            $errors[] = "There was an error updating the employee table. MySqli Error Number: " . $mysqli->errno . "";
            goto end;
            }
        $i++;
        }
goto redirect;
}
```

I am at a total loss and have been troubleshooting this all morning, I would really appreciate some help.

**UPDATE:** When I change `if(isset($_POST['update_submit']))` to `if(!isset($_POST['update_submit']))` and run it, I get an error:

```
"Notice: Undefined offset: 83 ... on line 31"
```

and line 31 is my

```
`$sql = ("UPDATE employee SET Emp_Name = '$name[$i]', Emp_Phone = '$phone[$i]', Emp_Start_Date = '$start[$i]', Paid_Leave = '$leave[$i]', Emp_ACA = '$aca[$i]', Lic_Auth_ID = '$licauth[$i]', Lic_Auth_Exp = '$authexp[$i]', Lic_Comp_ID = '$liccomp[$i]', Lic_Comp_Exp = '$compexp[$i]', MiscP_ID = '$miscp[$i]', Pos_ID = '$position[$i]', Emp_Active = '$active[$i]' WHERE Emp_ID = '$update'");`
```

I think that means that one of my `<input>` is not an `array`, right? If that is so, I don't know how that can be, the `table` is there and its created dynamically from the `database`.

**UPDATE2:** I think I've got something figured out, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried leaving the `name="Lic_Auth_Exp"` and `name="Lic_Comp_Exp"` and then removing two different `name` attributes from other `input` fields. After doing that it seemed to run the code. So the problem isn't because of these specific fields, but it seems to be because of there being more than 11 `$_POST` values being passed. I looked through the `php.ini` file to see if there were any limits on such a thing, but I didn't see anything. Does anyone know what could be causing this??

Comment: Are you getting any error while rendering the table or input elements when you mention the name attribute?

Comment: @Angel No, I just checked "view page source" in firefox and there are no errors showing. Good idea though, something I didn't think of.

Comment: Can you add firebug for firefox and check if there are any errors that are thrown?

Comment: I do have firebug installed, haven't used it much, but under the console it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Your button doesn't show up or work when you have the name attribute specified otherwise it shows up. Am I correct?

Comment: When you say "show up", you mean in the sense that it's set or not? If that's what you mean, then yes, that's correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22105/discussion-between-andrew-fox-and-angel)

Comment: @MECU I don't actually know, it's certainly not something I installed or turned on. If it comes pre installed on the WAMP server, then maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet I've spent well in excess of 14 hours troubleshooting this problem, and @angel was kind enough to try in depth as well. FINALLY I have it figured out.

The problem ended up being the `max_input_vars` not being set high enough in my `php.ini` file. Even bigger problem was that the setting doesn't actually exist until you add it, so when you look through the file, you don't see anything setting a limit in the first place!!

So, to recap. The issue wasn't because of the `name=""` attribute like I was lead to believe. I figured this out when I removed two other names from two different input fields, suddenly it worked fine and it was only when I had these extra fields that it wouldn't work. The next clue came thanks to @Jakub Sacha when he suggested to use the `var_dump($_POST)` function. When I started looking at the numbers, it finally clicked that the total amount of fields being passed added up to 1000. After a Google search for `PHP 1000 Limit` I found out about this `max_input_vars` setting.

Hopefully this will help someone else out and prevent hours of troubleshooting!

Answer (score 1):

1. dump `$_POST` in php to check is it what you expect.
2. validate form structure. does all inputs are inside same  tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dump `$_POST`". The form structure I believe it all good, each `<input>` is in it's own `<td>` and they are all within `<form>`.

Comment: make var_dump($_POST) in php, and check values (inside php code)

Comment: +1 for the `var_dump($_POST)` idea that I didn't know about! The result of that was as expected, I was getting 91 results for each input (I've got 91 `rows`), but then it all of a sudden stops at `Pos_ID` and returns only 90 results. There were no results for `$_POST['activeBox']`, could that be something??

Comment: I stand corrected, I ran it again (I had some inputs commented out) and it's actually only returning 83 rows for each input when there should be 91. I think we're onto something here!

Answer (score 0):

Extend the condition

```
if(isset($_POST['update_submit']) && $_POST['update_submit']=="you-given-name-just-null")
```

Comment: Although I appreciate the suggestion, why would simply removing the `name="Lic_Comp_Exp"` make everything else work? What is it about this one particular input name that's causing a problem?